# Is it possible to verify, whether a program has called `cfmakeraw()` to set its controlling terminal to raw mode?

Tags: bash, debian, shell, terminal, tty

> Is it possible to verify, whether a program has called `cfmakeraw()` to set its controlling terminal to raw mode?

I initially thought that it was possible to verify whether the terminal operated in raw mode by using `stty -a -F /dev/pts/N` and check whether `raw` was present in the output.

However, `raw` is nothing more than a combination setting (`man stty`):

```
   raw    same as -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -icanon -opost -isig -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -xcase min 1 time 0
```

and it says nothing about whether "input is available character by character" (see below).

In particular, canonical mode (counterpart to raw mode) is set depending on (`man termios`):

> The setting of the ICANON canon flag in c_lflag determines whether the
>   terminal is operating in canonical mode (ICANON set) or noncanonical
>   mode (ICANON unset).  By default, ICANON is set.

But `man stty` defines `icanon` as follows:

```
[-]icanon
              enable special characters: erase, kill, werase, rprnt
```

How can I see whether input is made available character by character (raw mode) or input is made available line by line (canonical mode)?

`man termios`:

```
   Raw mode
       cfmakeraw() sets the terminal to something like the "raw" mode of the old Version 7 terminal driver: input is available character by character, echoing is disabled, and all special processing of terminal input and output characters  is  disabled.   The  terminal  at‐
       tributes are set as follows:

           termios_p->c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP
                           | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
           termios_p->c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
           termios_p->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
           termios_p->c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
           termios_p->c_cflag |= CS8;
```

Comment: You can detect the state, but not the way it reaches it

Comment: How can I detect the state?

Comment: Note that `cfmakeraw()` is not a standard API, I don't expect that many applications will use it as that would make them non-portable.